# How to loop through JavaScript object in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron, script-tag

I want to loop through a `JavaScript` object and repeat an `html` script as many times as the object length.

Here, I have the following in a script tag

```
<script>
  var obj;

  ipcRenderer.on('requests-results', (event, hosSchema) => {
    obj = hosSchema
  })
</script>
```

`obj` is an array retrieved from `Mongo` database as the picture below shows:

[image]

and I have the following inside `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                   <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title">.1.</span>
                          <p>.2.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                          <a href="#">.3.</a>
                          <a href="#">.4.</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How can I loop through `obj` to repeat the code between `<div>` tag as many times as `obj.length`?

Comment: use json.parse. then a for loop in javascript. is that the question?

Comment: Technically JSON.parse() will turn JSON into a JavaScript object. The format the data is returned is JSON containing JSON objects. SEE:http://json.org/ and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: if you want to loop through an `object` in `HTML`, then why you have tagged `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `Handlebars` as @Amit mentioned.

first move out the code inside `<div id="page-inner">` as below:

```
<div id="page-inner">

</div>

<script id= "requests-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="row">
        {{#each requests}}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title">{{this.fieldName}}</span>
                    <p>{{this.fieldName}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <a href="#">{{this.fieldName}}</a>
                    <a href="#">{{this.fieldName}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
    </div>

</script>
```

Then inside another script page of type `text/javascript` you create the requests and assigned `obj/hosSchema` to it as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var requestInfo = document.getElementById('requests-template').innerHTML;

        var template = Handlebars.compile(requestInfo);

        var requestData = template({
            requests: obj
        })
        $('#page-inner').html(requestData);
</script>
```

NOTE: you need `handlebars` package installed (`npm install handlebars --save`)

Answer (score 0):

Use templating script like Handlebars.js, Mustache.js or underscore.js.
Check below link for more description.

http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var divlist = document.getElementsByTagName['div'];
var duplicate = null;
var rowIndex = -1;
var found = false;
for(var i = 0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    if(!found)
    for(var p = 0;p<divlist.length;p++)
        {
            if(rowIndex != -1 && duplicate != null)
                {
                    //set a Boolean to true and break
                    found = true;
                    break;  
                }

            if(divlist[p].className == "col-md-4 col-sm-4")
                {
                    //copy the element
                    duplicate = divlist[p];
                }
            else if(divlist[p].className == "row")
                {
                    //identify the row's index
                    rowIndex = p;
                }
        }
            //append the duplicate
            divlist[rowIndex].appendChild(duplicate);
}
```

Comment: Edited, I forgot a bracket. Whoops.